# xemacs: dotemacs config so that one can paste without getting "funny" chars

Tags: emacs, cygwin, dot-emacs

Copying text from websites via browser, paste into xemacs (21.4) buffer, and tildes, quotes, etc. don't copy correctly.

Example: he’s a dummy -> he\222s a dummy.

Can YOU copy & paste it without problems? If so, please help - how to config my .emacs to solve this.  Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, this works without problem on Emacs-23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn’t a clipboard or cygwin problem. If you save a UTF-8 text file with curly quotes in notepad and open it in XEmacs 21.4, you’ll get junk. According to the [XEmacs reference documentation](http://www.xemacs.org/Documentation/21.5/html/lispref_64.html#SEC862), Unicode is not supported before version 21.5.6. Maybe try a [later version](http://mirrors.xmission.com/cygwin/release/xemacs/)?

Comment: this worked; followed the links that you included above; installed latest xemacs version listed in the cygwin website (21.5 - experimental, but no problems) - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Fire this in your .emacs:

```
(set-clipboard-coding-system 'utf-16le-dos)
```

That should do it.  Don't forget to thi C-x C-e on that statement, or restart xemacs.

Comment: update: i tried the above and get an error (symbol's function definition is void: set-clipboard-coding-system).  Now I'm trying to figure out in which package that function is contained so that I can load it.  I find that many people set this function in their config (mostly to deal with Asian languages' characters), so I feel I'm getting somewhere, just not there yet...

Comment: set-clipboard-coding-system is an alias for `set-selection-coding-system' in `mule.el'.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to copy+paste smart quotes into XEmacs.  In this case, `'\222'` is the octal code for the character RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2019) encoded in the code page Windows-1252, which has the character encoding `0x92`.

XEmacs uses UTF-8 internally, so you'll have to configure the copy+paste to convert from Windows-1252 to UTF-8.  I don't know how to do that.

Comment: thanks Adam - great to know what is going on; hopefully someone will know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing to do is write a quick function that translates those characters using `replace-string`.

You could also have xemacs set to accept that code page directly.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to emacs, it works like a champ (GNU Emacs 23.0.91.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.0.6002) from [Emacsw32](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html) here). This may be the Emacsw32 patches in action.